# E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

z
I making an app to detect potholes this the main function camera fragment where I have to use OpenCV to get the desired result
while using OpenCV in android java I am facing this issue please help me
:opencv.org E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV Error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV

OpenCV version that I use is 3.4.2
and also have placed libs in the jniLibs folder but still OpenCV library not loading
I have to submit this app before tomorrow 19-DEC-2020 or I fail may semester please help  fellows

```
    package com.example.dpgra.defectdetect;
    
  
    
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    
    import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
    import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
    import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
    import org.opencv.core.Core;
    import org.opencv.core.Mat;
    import org.opencv.core.Point;
    import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
    import org.opencv.core.Size;
    import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
    
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    import model.Darknet;
    import model.Pothole;
    import model.PotholeList;
    
    public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2, View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    
        private View rootView;
        private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
        private Darknet net;
        private static CameraFragment cameraFragment;
        private PotholeList potholeList;
        private Integer OrientationIsValid;
        private double confidenceThresh;
        BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback ;
        Mat imageMat;
       // JavaCameraView javaCamera2View;
    
    
    
        private static String TAG ="CameraFragment";
        static
        {
    
            if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV Installed Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV Failed");
            }
        }
    
        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        private CameraFragment() {
            super();
            potholeList = PotholeList.getInstance();
            OrientationIsValid = 0;
            confidenceThresh = .6;
        }
    
        /**
         * Returns the one instance of the camera fragment.
         *
         * @return the camera fragment
         */
        public static CameraFragment getInstance() {
            if (cameraFragment == null) {
                cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();
            }
            return cameraFragment;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
    
            mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            }
    
    
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
            this.rootView = rootView;
   
            mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
            //Check if the device is not an emulator
            String myDeviceModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
    
    
            if (!myDeviceModel.toLowerCase().contains("sdk")) {
                //Rotate the camera view 90 degrees clockwise
                mOpenCvCameraView.setAngle(90);
    
            }
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton2).setOnClickListener(this);
            mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
   
            SeekBar seekBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    
    
    
            /**
             * Makes sure opencv can load successfully.
             */
    
             mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this.getActivity()) {
                @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
                @Override
                public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
    
                    switch (status) {
                        case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS: {
                            //Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
   
                            imageMat = new Mat();
                            break;
    
                        }
                        default: {
                            super.onManagerConnected(status);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
    
    
            return root view;
        }
    
        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has started. After this method is invoked
         * the frames will start to be delivered to client via the onCameraFrame() callback.
         *
         * @param width  -  the width of the frames that will be delivered
         * @param height - the height of the frames that will be delivered
         */
        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    
            
            String cfgFile = getPath("yolov2-tiny2.cfg", this.getActivity());
            String weightsFile = getPath("yolov2-tiny2_58800.weights", this.getActivity());
    
            if (cfgFile != null && weightsFile != null) {
                net = new Darknet(cfgFile, weightsFile);
            }
            mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(CameraBridgeViewBase.VISIBLE);
        }
    
        /**
         * This method is invoked when camera preview has been stopped for some reason.
         * No frames will be delivered via onCameraFrame() callback after this method is called.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    
        }
    
        /**
         * This method is invoked when delivery of the frame needs to be done.
         * The returned values - is a modified frame which needs to be displayed on the screen.
         * TODO: pass the parameters specifying the format of the frame (BPP, YUV or RGB and etc)
         *
         * @param inputFrame
         */
        @Override
        public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
            Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, frame, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2RGB);
            Mat mRgbaT = frame;
    /*        old_mRgbaT = frame.t();
            Core.flip(old_mRgbaT, old_mRgbaT, 1);
            Imgproc.resize(old_mRgbaT, mRgbaT, frame.size());
            old_mRgbaT.release();
            */
            Mat temp = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < OrientationIsValid; i++) {
    
                temp = frame.t();
                Core.flip(temp, temp, 1);
                Imgproc.resize(temp, mRgbaT, frame.size());
                temp.release();
            }
    
            int cols = mRgbaT.cols();
            int rows = mRgbaT.rows();
            Size cropSize;
            if ((float) cols / rows > 1) {
                cropSize = new Size(rows * 1, rows);
            } else {
                cropSize = new Size(cols, cols / 1);
            }
            int y1 = (int) (rows - cropSize.height) / 2;
            int y2 = (int) (y1 + cropSize.height);
            int x1 = (int) (cols - cropSize.width) / 2;
            int x2 = (int) (x1 + cropSize.width);
            Mat subFrame = mRgbaT.submat(y1, y2, x1, x2);
            cols = subFrame.cols();
            rows = subFrame.rows();
            int sevarity = 0;
            if (net != null) {
                double confidence, xCenter, yCenter, width, height = 0;
                Mat retMat = net.forwardLoadedNetwork(mRgbaT);
                for (int i = 0; i < retMat.rows(); i++) {
                    confidence = retMat.get(i, 5)\[0\];
                    if (confidence > confidenceThresh) {
                        printMat(retMat.row(i));
                        //System.out.println("YESSSSSS");
                        xCenter = retMat.get(i, 0)\[0\] * mRgbaT.cols();
                        yCenter = retMat.get(i, 1)\[0\] * mRgbaT.rows();
                        width = retMat.get(i, 2)\[0\] * mRgbaT.cols();
                        height = retMat.get(i, 3)\[0\] * mRgbaT.rows();
                        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgbaT, new Point((xCenter - width / 2), (yCenter - height / 2)), new Point(xCenter + width / 2
                                , yCenter + height / 2), new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
                        Imgproc.putText(mRgbaT, String.format("%.4f", new Double(confidence * 100)) + "%", new Point((xCenter - width / 2), (yCenter - height / 2) - 5)
                                , 1, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
                        sevarity++;
                    }
                }
                retMat.release();
                subFrame.release();
                if (sevarity > 0) {
                    createPothole(sevarity);
                }
            } else {
                //Log.i("System", "Problem forwarding network");
            }
            return mRgbaT;
        }
    
        private Pothole createPothole(int severity) {
            Pothole pothole = null;
            if (this.getActivity() != null) {
                Location location = ((MainActivity) this.getActivity()).getLocation();
                if (location != null) {
                    pothole = new Pothole(location, createPotholeId(), severity);
                    addToPotholeList(pothole);
                }
            }
    
            return pothole;
        }
    
        /**
         * Creates the id string for a pothole.
         *
         * @return the pothole id
         */
        public String createPotholeId() {
            PotholeList list = PotholeList.getInstance();
            int num = 0;
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                String lastId = list.get(list.size() - 1).getId();
                num = Integer.parseInt(lastId.substring(1));
            }
            String retId = "p" + (num + 1);
            return retId;
        }
    
        /**
         * Prints the returned matrix outputted from the network.
         *
         * @param mat the mat to print
         */
        private void printMat(Mat mat) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows(); i++) {
                //System.out.print("\[ ");
                for (int n = 0; n < mat.cols(); n++) {
                    try {
                        //System.out.printf( "%.2f ", mat.get(i, n)\[0\]);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        //System.out.print( " " );
                    }
    
                }
                //System.out.println("\]");
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
    
            try {
                if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
                    Log.d("Debug", "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
                    mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback .SUCCESS);
    
    
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("Debug", "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
                    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this.getActivity(), mLoaderCallback);
                }
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
                Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "OpenCV is required to run this feature. Please install OpenCV from the Google Play Store or download the APK from their official website.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Gets the path of a file and create it in the app memory.
         *
         * @param fileType the file to find
         * @param context  context
         * @return the pathname
         */
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        private static String getPath(String fileType, Context context) {
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            String\[\] pathNames = {};
            String fileName = "";
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
            try {
                pathNames = assetManager.list("yolo");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (String filePath : pathNames) {
                System.out.println(filePath);
                if (filePath.endsWith(fileType)) {
                    fileName = filePath;
                    break;
                }
            }
            BufferedInputStream inputStream;
            try {
                // Read data from assets.
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(assetManager.open(fileName));
                byte\[\] data = new byte\[inputStream.available()\];
                inputStream.read(data);
                inputStream.close();
    
                // Create copy file in storage.
                File outFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                os.write(data);
                os.close();
                // Return a path to file which may be read in common way.
                return outFile.getAbsolutePath();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //Log.i(TAG, "Failed to upload a file");
            }
            return "";
        }
    
        /**
         * Adds the pothole to the pothole list.
         *
         * @param pothole the pothole to add
         */
        public boolean addToPotholeList(Pothole pothole) {
            return potholeList.add(pothole);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            OrientationIsValid++;
            if (OrientationIsValid > 3) {
                OrientationIsValid = 0;
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            confidenceThresh = (double) i / 100;
            TextView textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.confidence);
            textView.setText("Confidence Threshold: " + (confidenceThresh * 100) + "%");
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    
        }
    }
```